# I need to give time on one-sided gateway using broadcast

Tags: time, broadcast, ntp

server:

```
server 192.168.1.50 iburst
server 192.168.1.150 iburst
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
broadcast 192.168.1.255 minpoll 4 maxpoll 
disable auth
```

client:

```
broadcastclient
disable auth
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: server:
 server 192.168.1.50 iburst
 server 192.168.1.150 iburst
 restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
 broadcast 192.168.1.255 minpoll 4 maxpoll disable auth

client: broadcastclient disable auth

Comment: what is the output from `ntpq -pcrv` - please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46647192/edit) your question to include the output, and please use the code format to reformat your config shown.